# An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two stored procedures and I am inserting the result sets of one stored procedure into a table in sql server 2012. However, I am getting these two errors and I do not know how to solve them.
    1st error : An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.
    2nd error : Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

```
Here is my stored procedure code,

USE [my_DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_1] 
@Week int = 1,
@Year int = 2014
AS
BEGIN
declare @current_week int
set @current_week = datepart (week, getdate()) 
while @Week <= @current_week
begin
truncate table [my_DB].[dbo].[tb_name]
insert into [my_DB].[dbo].[tb_name]
exec sp_2 @Week,@Year
select @Week as Week_Number,* from [my_DB].[dbo].[tb_name] (nolock)
set @Week = @Week + 1
end
END

Here is what I am trying to do when I am getting the errors.

insert into tb_name exec dbo.sp_1 @Week=1, @Year=2014

Any ideas would be helpful.

Thanks.
```

Comment: Can you provide the schema for tb_name and the definition for sp_2? Also, there is not a way around with procedure nesting - you will need to go about this another way (function could be an option for either of these)

Comment: check the number or columns in that table a number of columns returned from this stored procedure. Insert and Exec statements can be nested. Put your truncate statement in a separate procedure and call that procedure here in begin end block instead of executing this truncate statement.

Comment: If I add a new column in the table to match the results, it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Can you change sp_2 so you aren't forced to use a while loop here for inserting data? It seems to me the problem is that sp_2 can't handle multiple sets of data. It also seems that your looping construct has some serious issues. You keep setting the Week variable to the same value each iteration through your loop. And why NOLOCK? Are you aware of all the ramifications of that hint?

Comment: sp_2 provides appropriate result. I think the problem lies in me trying to use insert-exec twice. Once in the stored procedure and another when trying to insert the data in the table from the stored procedure. Is there any way around this insert-exec?